# where is ~/.jupyter folder

Tags: linux, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Linux, and I am still struggling to find folder in the directory.

So, I am trying to locate

```
~/.jupyter.
```

in order to find config.py.

I typed

```
find . -name "jupyter_notebook_config.py"
```

Then, it generated following:

```
./.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

But when I checked the Home directory, I cannot find anything like " .jupyter".

Is it something hidden?

Is there any different way to open/locate folder in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files with names starting with `.` is hidden by default. You need to add `-a` for `ls`, if you are using `ls`.

See also [What does 'a' stand for in 'ls -a' command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888915/what-does-a-stand-for-in-ls-a-command)